Does a single ball undergoing ideal simple harmonic motion count as being in thermodynamic equilibrium?
(Posting this and deleting a previous similar post to make the question more clear.)
Suppose we have an isolated system inside a box consisting of a spring and a ball attached to the spring. The ball is undergoing simple harmonic oscillation, but no friction or drag is present.
Can we say this system is in thermodynamic equilibrium or not? Is it undergoing a process or is it static?
On one hand, no heat or work interaction is occurring with any outside system, and the system will have the ball continue to oscillate forever. Moreover, its internal energy is fixed. On the other hand, some texts include mechanical equilibrium as part of the requirement for a thermodynamic equilibrium, and the ball inside the system is not in mechanical equilibrium since it has a nonzero net force due to the spring. Moreover, there is clearly macroscopic change always occurring, which Wikipedia says should not occur in thermodynamic equilibrium. How do you classify the state of this system?

Are you asking if the system has a temperature due to the oscillation? If you really asking if the system is thermodynamic equilibrium, you have to define what it is in thermodynamic equilibrium with?  Consider a brick in space. It is thermolytic equilibrium with the temperature of space (due to background radiation. Its system cannot be in thermal equilibrium with itself, unless it is somehow perfectly insulated from the rest of the universe.

The system is in thermodynamic equilibrium much as, say, the idealized container of gas is. Real container walls creep under load; they have a vapor pressure; they have surface tension; they are permeable to gas. But we often ignore these aspects, as you are ignoring dissipative processes.
You've eliminated any way for entropy to increase in your model, so your model is evidently at thermodynamic equilibrium.
Now, we can't construct a real version of your system, but the above conclusion may be suitably accurate for a thought experiment and some useful predictive models. For example, if I look at the ball in free motion at two different times, I can predict that its temperature will be the same.
Definitions in which internal macroscale motion or "change" preclude equilibrium assume that these processes are sufficiently real as to be dissipative. Ultimately, we have to draw the line somewhere and assume that the kinetics of certain processes are slow enough to be negligible, as true global equilibrium corresponds to a heat death scenario. If $dS$ (with entropy $S$) is justifiably small for some system over some time period, I'm willing to accept a label of local thermodynamic equilibrium.

I think I understand. First, I looked over what textbooks had to say about the term, and I found that the insightful ones were Landau & Lifshitz, Don Lemons, and Herbert Callen. Based on those readings, I gather that a physical definition of thermodynamic equilibrium is that it is simply the state that an isolated system will tend to given long enough time spans. Would you agree with this definition (even tentatively)? Or do you have a better characterization?

It seems that the necessity of mechanical equilibrium is a red-herring for cases where there are no dissipative forces (like my example)? I realize there are no real-life system without dissipation, so my point is very, very theoretical. Is all this correct or am I misunderstanding something? Any feedback would be immensely appreciated.

(To simplify my first comment, I could say, thermodynamic equilibrium is when all transient behaviors are eliminated when the system is isolated (the isolated condition is needed to eliminate the possibility of driving forces). Since the motion of the spring+ball is not transient when no friction is present, the system is in thermodynamic equilibrium, despite the fact that mechanical equilibrium is not achieved. Let me know if this is wrong.)

All this sounds reasonable. Note that "transient" is often itself defined in terms of equilibrium, so some circularity might be present. That doesn't bother me; physics isn't logic. It's arguably more important to be consistent: As we've discussed, the important aspect is that everyone's clear on how the system is allowed/expected to evolve for the model and its use.

Despite its name, a textbook in thermodynamics is, for the most part, not concerned with dynamics. In fact, it can be rigorously formulated starting from the notion of ordering among equilibrium states. I think it becomes immensely difficult to define thermodynamic equilibrium for a system for which we are not entirely sure how to define its thermodynamic properties (intensive or extensive). That being said,
Your question seems to lean more towards a condition for a "steady state" rather than thermodynamic equilibrium itself. I'm considering the thermodynamic system as everything inside the box: the ball and the space it has to oscillate.
However, it's crucial to note that a steady state in a harmonic oscillator is not the same as thermodynamic equilibrium. While a steady state implies constancy in certain observables, thermodynamic equilibrium is a broader set of conditions, including uniformity and constancy of macroscopic properties such as temperature, pressure, and entropy throughout the system, which does not seem definable in your case.
Additionally, in thermodynamic equilibrium, there should be no net exchange of energy with the surroundings, and I am not sure if that condition is met in your question. If we are considering the system as everything inside the box, then the net force is zero because the system seems to be in mechanical equilibrium. If we are looking only at the ball, then there is the restoring force of the spring. However, this doesn't seem to affect the thermodynamics of the box, as it does not appear to influence changes in macroscopic variables such as volume, pressure, or temperature (of the box or the ball).
In the case of the isolated harmonic oscillator, it can indeed reach a steady state where its oscillation parameters remain constant, but it does not achieve thermodynamic equilibrium because there is no uniformity or constancy in macroscopic properties, and there is no exchange of energy with the surroundings. Therefore, while the system may appear to exhibit characteristics of a steady state, it does not satisfy the criteria for thermodynamic equilibrium, mainly because we cannot fully define thermodynamic equilibrium for the condition you've described so far.
When we try to define equilibrium for a system such as yours, the literature https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2268 usually defines a reservoir or surroundings with well-defined temperature, pressure, or volume, though not always using all of them. We say that there is contact between both until the system reaches a certain state. From there, we isolate the system and it is said that the initial state has some sort of Gibbs ensemble with a defined temperature. We could say that if your system had undergone this type of procedure, its state now would be similar to its equilibrium version.

Not really an expert here, but I would say the standard thing people would say here is that the system is not thermodynamic at all because it doesn’t have a thermodynamically large number of degrees of freedom.
So the question “is this system in thermal equilibrium” doesn’t even make sense.

I concede my example is very contrived in the study of thermodynamics (no one will bother thinking about my example except as an attempt to make a confusing counterexample to something), but I disagree with your post. First, thermodynamics is supposed to be very general when it comes to delineating what counts of a system (and I am concerned specifically with classical thermo, not stat mech). Second, please be wary that "thermal equilibrium" is not the same thing as "thermodynamic equilibrium." Despite similar names, they are distinct concepts!
